# how to save a filesystem file in Office add-ins

Tags: office-js

office add-ins is a javaScript project，every add-ins user is a client。
what should I do that save a fileSystem file （*.json）in add-ins。

Answer (score 0):

An Office add-in is a web application. Web applications cannot directly save files to the file system (except cookies). But a web application can implement a download UI that enables the user to download and save a file to the file system.